# If I install Ubuntu 10.10 over 10.04, will all my programs be erased?

Tags: installation, upgrade, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will there be data loss for upgrade ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5435/will-there-be-data-loss-for-upgrade)

If I want to install 10.10 replacing 10.04 and I select overwrite existing linux distro, will it keep my /home folder and all my settings for programs and such?
If not, what would be a good way to back up all my programs and their data?

Comment: Dupe of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/5435/will-there-be-data-loss-for-upgrade

Comment: Hadn't seen that other one before. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doing a clean install of 10.10 over 10.04 will preserve your home folder.

But... you should still back it up anyway (just in case something goes wrong).

Comment: Does this really work with a clean install? I'm impressed if it does!

Comment: @fluteflute It also does this if it installs over a copy of Windows. It's been this way since 7.04 at least...

Comment: Ah the Migration Assistant? Makes sense now :)

Comment: Sweeeet! Thanks! That really helps. That's what I was hoping to do. So I can just select overwrite existing linux distro then? I wanted to do with a clean install because every time I've upgraded it has failed with something. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you install over it, yes they will.  If you upgrade, your programs should stay installed and keep on working if everything goes smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your file and settings intact, then your best option would be to simply use the update manager to upgrade to 10.10. You can find it in **System** -> **Administration**, and it's toward the bottom. When you run it and refresh the list, you should see an option at the top of the windows with an option to upgrade the distro.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If you have a separate partition for /home and you choose the manual partitioning method and don't format the /home partition but mount it as home, then your data will be preserved.