# Upgrade from Intrepid to Lucid, using CDROM

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, installation, 9.04

I want to upgrade a PC from Intrepd to Lucid, but I can only go as far as 9.10, even though I have "Show only LTS" enabled in Sources. I have a 10.04 CD, is it possible to upgrade to Lucid, after I pop it in and run some command?

Thanks.

EDIT: This is a development PC, and doesnt have /home partition. (I know, not good practice). So, a re-install is the absolute last option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5435/will-there-be-data-loss-for-upgrade/5436#5436) to a similar question applies to you in this case.

Comment: yeah, i guess ill have to do 2 jumps. thanks :(

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to skip an awful lot of development there. Two years worth of upgrades is quite a leap. You may want to do the upgrade to 9.10, and then to 10.04 from there. The only way to know for sure, of course, is to pop in a 10.04 CD and then attempt an upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

For non-LTS releases, the furthest you can usually upgrade is the next release. LTS releases can usually jump from LTS to the next LTS.

This is the case because there's a certain amount of transformation that each release does to the old install. LTS installers know the state of the previous LTS but it's not practical (from a testing standpoint) for every installer to have every combination of previous install.

I'm already surprised that it'll go as far as 9.10.