# Upgrading from a previous version of Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will there be data loss for upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5435/will-there-be-data-loss-for-upgrade)

Can we upgrade a previous version of ubuntu to the latest version **without losing data** ? (For example, will I be able to upgrade the 10.10 version to 11.04, which is due to be released in April of 2011?) I mean, there is a new version coming out every 6 months, so it will be convenient if we are able to upgrade without losing on the data .

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Upgrades do not erase your settings/data. You can run the command `sudo do-release-upgrade` in terminal to check for available upgrades. Run `do-release-upgrade -h` to see options, such as how to upgrade early (prior to release).

Also, if you know what you're doing, you can partition your hard drive to place your /home on its own partition.[1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) This enables you to wipe your install if anything goes wrong and reinstall without losing your settings/data.

Comment: Do not forget to make a backup, just in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the update manager. It will report if the new version is available. It won't destroy your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely update from within Ubuntu using the Update Manager though there is other options available, the following [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade) to the Ubuntu website should provide you with enough info (though it details 10.04 to 10.10 it will be the same for 10.10 to 11.04).