# Will files and data be deleted when I update from 10.10 to 11.04?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will there be data loss for upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5435/will-there-be-data-loss-for-upgrade)

I am thinking to update from 10.10 to 11.04.

Will any files or data be deleted?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the upgrade, you can choose to keep all your files, including previous kernel version and old libraries. So, an upgrade wont delete any of your files, but you may remove the old libraries and programs, at your choice.