# How to upgrade Ubuntu without losing packages?

Tags: installation, upgrade, package-management

I'm currently running Ubuntu *10.something* and I have some special packages installed for server tasks.

I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 12 and I'm afraid that I'll lose these packages.

So what will happen if I chose the upgrade option when I put in the installation DVD? Will I lose the packages or not?

Comment: From my experience: the upgrade system of Ubuntu 13.04 (from 12.10) asked to me to choice between save the packages installed or not, I have chosen *Save the Packages*. But after the upgrade procedure there was an **error** and all my installed packages just gone..

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/92926/62483

Answer (score 3):

In theory, the upgrade should smoothly take over your package selection -- with possible exception of packages from outside of the main distribution tree (like custom launchpad repositories). However, to be on the safe side, back up your package selection:

```
dpkg --get-selections > packages.txt
```

Later, you can restore these selections by issuing (as root)

```
cat packages.txt | dpkg --set-selections && apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

In any case, remember to back up your system before upgrading, including `/etc`. And make sure your backups work!