# Ubuntu Upgrade to 14.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

If I upgrade my ubuntu 13.10 to ubuntu 14.04 LTS will all of my previous upgrades remain or not ?

Comment: If by previous upgrades you are referring to your data and programs: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5435/will-there-be-data-loss-for-upgrade

Comment: Is your Home directory located on the same partition as your Ubuntu?  If it is, you may need to back up you Home before you upgrade.  Also, you could experience some minor compatibility issues with your upgrade.  I did not, but some have.

Comment: By previous upgrades i am referring to my currently installed libraries and programs on ubuntu 13.10. Kindly , clarify me will all of my previous installed libraries be overwritten or lost when i upgarde my ubuntu 13.10 to ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not lose any files/data when you do an upgrade using the command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

What [los-teh](https://askubuntu.com/users/284699/los-teh) told is also true. You can lose some software/libaries what are not comatible with Ubuntu 14.04, but most software for Ubuntu 13.10 will also work on 14.04.

Good luck with the upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Your files / Data should be safe, but you should always back up your data as precaution

With regards to software/libraries - you may loose some applications if your PPAs arent yet compatible with 14.04