# To update or not to update

Tags: updates, nfs, 9.10

My research lab has a super computer cluster, however they are all using Ubuntu 9.10. I need to install `nfs-kernel-server` on the individual nodes so I can access to and process the files from a single node. But I am unable to `apt-get install nfs-kernel-server` or `apt-get update`. If I am understanding the situation correctly, it is because Ubuntu 9.10 is no longer being supported so there are no update list.

They question now is, should I try to update it to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The cluster does however, has some NFS and NIS set up. I can't afford to have them ruined. Will updating to 14.04 risk anything? I am fairly new to Linux so I don't know the details of how the cluster is set up.

Comment: We recommend backing up anything you "can't afford to have ruined" among other things....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will there be data loss for upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5435/will-there-be-data-loss-for-upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking can be described by this metaphor:

"I've got these leaking boots and there's this freezing rain and my feet are really cold, but I don't want to run around barefoot while getting my boots repaired..."

Well, get some spare boots (take a system backup of your cluster), get your boots repaired (upgrade your cluster during its maintenance window) and if anything goes wrong, keep walking in your current boots (restore your system back-up and learn from your mistakes and try again and again and again until it works)...

Or hire a shoemaker and have him repair your boots while you wear them.  (Get a consultant and have him/her/it upgrade your system for you).

*Just get the <strike>damn</strike> thing upgraded: you're a disaster waiting to happen!*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get support you need to be running a supported release of Ubuntu. 9.10 has not been supported for quite some time now. When support for a release is terminated, the archive is moved off the main updates mirrors and onto an old releases archive server. There will be no further updates to it, security or otherwise. If you want a secure system, it needs to be kept up to date.