# how to install ubuntu 16.10 from 16.04 without data loss

Tags: 16.04, gnome, update-manager, 16.10

How to install ubuntu 16.10 from 16.04.1 without losing data in / and home folders.
i have over 100gb worth apps installed and
cannot afford to lose them.
need help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will there be data loss if I upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5435/will-there-be-data-loss-if-i-upgrade) and [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)